# MYSQL how do I get a SUM of the checkins?

Tags: mysql, sum

```
SELECT promotions.`sms_promo_id`, places.`id`, places.`name`, insights.`checkins`, insights.`likes`, insights.`place_id`
FROM promotions INNER JOIN places INNER JOIN insights
ON promotions.`id` = places.`promotion_id` AND places.`id` = insights.`place_id`
GROUP BY place_id
```

This sql query works fine but I lose my checkin data when I use the GROUP BY command. How do I sum the checkins of a specific places.'id', say 2, before I group all of the 2's together?

```
Example:
2, 52 checkins
2, 11 checkins
```

**I want:** 2, 63 checkins

**current sql produces** 2, 52 checkins

Comment: What type of SQL DBMS are you using? Most have a 'SUM()' aggregate function.

Comment: I like how your sample query has 6 columns in the select list, yet your sample output and desired result only seem to have 2.

Comment: @David: Almost certainly MySQL (so I added the tag), the backtick quoting stuff is a MySQL-ism.

Comment: @mu is too short: As is the incomplete GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT promotions.`sms_promo_id`, places.`id`, places.`name`, sum(insights.`checkins`), insights.`likes`, insights.`place_id`
FROM promotions INNER JOIN places INNER JOIN insights
ON promotions.`id` = places.`promotion_id` AND places.`id` = insights.`place_id`
GROUP BY promotions.`sms_promo_id`, places.`id`, places.`name`, insights.`likes`, insights.`place_id`
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query does not match your output. What you seem to want is:

```
select place_id, sum(checkins)
from insights
group by place_id
```

If you add more fields or more joins you may end up subgrouping by other criteria or adding extra rows. These will lead to invalid results.